# Clangd LSP shows unknown type name 'interface' in dsound.h

Tags: c++, winapi, neovim, directsound, clangd

I just starting working on a Win32 application and I'm editing in Neovim. I'm running off WSL and using clangd as my LSP. To compile I'm using Microsoft cl and it's building the binary fine.

I was refactoring some code and I encountered a weird LSP error when moving my `#include <dsound.h>` from it's original main.cpp to a new header file (windows_sound.h). My LSP gave me the following complaint: clang: In included file: unknown type name 'interface'.

This error shows up even when it's the only thing in the file (without include guards). However, if I move the include into an empty .cpp (windows_sound.cpp) the LSP gives me no errors. Any idea what's going on?

My .clangd (which points to MingW64's windows header files):

```
CompileFlags:
    Add:
        - "--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu"
        - "-std=c++20"
        - "-fms-extensions"
        - "Wall"
        - "-isystem/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/"
```

My clangd version: 15.0.6

nvim version: 0.8.0-1210

The only additional thing I do in my config is I modified the clangd command to:

```
cmd =
{
    "clangd",
    "--header-insertion=never",
},
```

Comment: Which file is reporting that error?  `dsound.h` [has no mention of a symbol named `interface`](https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio/blob/master/include/dsound.h).

Comment: What happens if you give your header an `.hpp` extension instead of `.h`? If that makes it work, then the issue is related to language detection (clangd thinks the `.h` file is a C header).

Comment: @HighCommander4, I changed it to .hpp and it no longer gave me errors! If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as solved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occuring in an `.h` but not in a `.cpp` file may indicate that clangd is treating the `.h` file as a C header rather than a C++ header.

One solution is to rename the header to `.hpp` which identifies it as a C++ header.

Another solution is to instruct clangd to parse `.h` files in your project as C++ headers by adding the following to a [`.clangd` file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html) in the project root:

```yaml
If:
  PathMatch: .*\.h

CompileFlags:
  Add: [-xc++-header]
```

Clangd does have some heuristics to classify `.h` files as C++, e.g. if there is a file with the same name but a `.cpp` extension next to it, it will treat the `.h` file as C++. There are [plans](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/123) to expand this heuristic to consider actual inclusion relationships in the project (i.e. treat an `.h` file as C++ if any `.cpp` file in the project includes it), but until then one of the above two workarounds may be necessary.